# Combined aggregates into a single SQL table

Tags: t-sql

We have a table which is a bit like this:

```
Year Episode  Code
2000       1  A001
2000       1  A001
2000       1  C007
2000       2  A001
2000       2  B001
```

It's referencing another table, in which the combination of `Year` and `Episode` is unique, but this table I'm working with just lists the selection of codes applied to each episode.

What I'm trying to do is create a table that returns a per-year count of total episodes and episodes that have a particular code.  I can't just do a simple "COUNT(*)" of the code, because one episode may have the same code multiple times.

Can anyone see a viable way to do what I am attempting?

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are after. You need at least SQL Server 2005 for the pivot function.

```
create table MyTable (
    [Year] datetime,
    Episode int,
    Code nvarchar(20)
)

insert into MyTable values ('01-01-2000', 1, 'A001')
insert into MyTable values ('01-01-2000', 1, 'A001')
insert into MyTable values ('01-01-2000', 1, 'C007')
insert into MyTable values ('01-01-2000', 2, 'A001')
insert into MyTable values ('01-01-2000', 2, 'B001')
insert into MyTable values ('01-01-2000', 2, 'B001')
insert into MyTable values ('01-01-2001', 1, 'A001')
insert into MyTable values ('01-01-2002', 1, 'A001')
insert into MyTable values ('01-01-2003', 1, 'C007')

select [Code], [2000], [2001], [2002]
from (
      select Code,     
      DATEPART(year, [Year]) as date,
      count(Episode) as instances
      from MyTable
      group by DATEPART(year, [year]), code) as o
pivot
(
    sum(instances) for date in ([2000], [2001], [2002])
) as p
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By “create a table” I'm going to assume you know how to create a table from a result set. So this reduces to: **What query will return a result set with a per-year count of episodes**.

You cite duplicate tuples as a problem. You're right, they are a problem; why are they there? What is the semantic difference between one tuple of `(2000, 1, 'A001')` versus three identical ones?

The `DISTINCT` clause is designed to strip those; I recommend using it any time you don't know an explicit good reason to keep duplicates in the result set.

So if duplicates aren't meaningful, and a result set is sufficient for you to progress, then:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    year,
    COUNT(episode) AS episode_count
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        year,
        episode
    FROM episode_code
    WHERE
        code = 'A001'
    ) AS episode_for_code
GROUP BY year
```

will give a count of episodes by year, for `episode_code` tuples with a specified code.

Once you have that, I'd investigate why you have duplicates in `episode_code` at all, and remove them unless you get a good answer.